# Setting up cloud code in back4app to trigger post API to add to ESP

Tags: javascript, api, email, triggers, back4app

I am new to creating APIs and cloud code and I am not sure how to set up an API to add/update users from my back4app database table to my sendinblue (ESP) contact list.

Can I please get some assistance on what needs to be in the main.js file uploaded and what needs to be done to make any updates to a user record get sent to sendinblue? I'm not seeing anything in the logs showing the code was triggered to be successful or fail.

Below is what I am trying to send when the "_User" table is updated in back4app.

Parse.Cloud.aftersave("_User"), function(request, response) {
  curl -X POST https://api.sendinblue.com/v3/contacts
  -H 'content-type:application/json'
  -H 'api-key:APIKEY'
  -d '{"listIds":["3"],"email":"test@email.com","updateEnabled":"true"}'
  });

Answer (score 0):

Access the logs going to Server Settings > Logs > Settings > Server System Log.

Check [here](https://docs.parseplatform.org/cloudcode/guide/#aftersave-triggers) the correct afterSave structure. Also, you can send an HTTP request using the [Parse.Cloud.httpRequest](https://docs.parseplatform.org/cloudcode/guide/#networking).

Comment: Thanks, I have been trying and still having trouble. Is there a way to trigger the http request? 

End goal is to have back4app send the update to the esp each time a used is added or updated in real-time. Is that even possible?